# Angular problem with @ngrx, "," expected error during angular server run

Tags: angular, server, ngrx

When I run angular server, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/@ngrx/component-store/src/component-store.d.ts:69:83 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

69     select<Selectors extends Observable<unknown>[], Result>(...args: [...selectors: Selectors, projector: Projector<Selectors, Result>]): Observable<Result>;
                                                                                     ~
../../node_modules/@ngrx/component-store/src/component-store.d.ts:69:105 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

69     select<Selectors extends Observable<unknown>[], Result>(...args: [...selectors: Selectors, projector: Projector<Selectors, Result>]): Observable<Result>;
                                                                                                           ~
../../node_modules/@ngrx/component-store/src/component-store.d.ts:71:21 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

71         ...selectors: Selectors,
                       ~
../../node_modules/@ngrx/component-store/src/component-store.d.ts:72:18 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

72         projector: Projector<Selectors, Result>,
                    ~
../../node_modules/@ngrx/component-store/src/component-store.d.ts:73:15 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

73         config: SelectConfig
```

The angular is on monorepo, and I run angular with this command:

```
npx nx serve web-app
```

do you know what is the problem that ngrx is making me here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Error text is not always shows place with actual error. It may be caused your code with ngrx. Try to check it for errors.

Comment: check if you are using an up to date target in your tsconfig

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a TypeScript issue.
Make sure that the versions of Angular and NgRx are the same.